# Know when jqXHRs of an array are all completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise

I'm trying to run some code once all the `jqXHR` elements of an array are completed (have either succeeded or failed).

You can see the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkjcrdtz/4/

Basically I'm expecting the `always` hook from here:

```
$.when
    .apply(undefined, reqs)
    .always(function(data) {
      console.log('ALL ALWAYS', data);
    });
```

to run when all the requests that were piled up there have either succeeded or failed. Currently, you can observe in the console that `ALL ALWAYS` is logged earlier.

Comment: As soon as one request fails it will trigger the `$.when.fail()` and then call the `always()`. Nothing aborts the other requests so they continue to resolve even after the `$.when` has failed

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.11.1

Comment: jQuery is too old, that version doesn't have catch and you are not returning the caught promise so as soon as one fails it'll go in the always part. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkjcrdtz/5/) for fixed version.

Comment: If you cannot change jQuery function you could turn those buggy old jQuery deferred into real promises with: `Promise.resolve($.get(....).then().catch().finally()` And no reason to use `$.when` when you can do `Promise.all([promise1,promise2 ...])`

Comment: Yeah I was suspecting it's the version. Sadly it's a bit too risky to change the it, so I think I'll go the Promise way since we only need to support Edge, FF and Chrome

Comment: If only supporting modern browsers could use `fetch()  API` instead of `$.ajax` and `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for modern browsers would be to use the newer [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API along with `Promise.all()`

```js
var makeReq = function(url, pos) {
  var finalUrl = url + pos;

  // intentionally make this request a failed one
  if (pos % 2 === 0) {
    finalUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/423423rfvzdsv";
  }

  return fetch(finalUrl).then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Request for user #', pos);
    //  if successful request return data promise otherwise return something
    //  that can be used to filter out in final results
    return resp.ok ? resp.json() : {error: true, status: resp.status, id: pos }
  })
};

// mock API
var theUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";
var reqs = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  reqs.push(makeReq(theUrl, i));
}

Promise.all(reqs).then(function(results) {
  console.log('---- ALL DONE ----')
  // filter out good requests
  results.forEach(function(o) {
    if (o.error) {
      console.log(`No results for user #${o.id}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`User #${o.id} name = ${o.name}`);
    }
  })
})
```